# List View/Recycler View Pre Loading Animation

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I want to make a loading animation like the screenshot attached. I am unable to find it on the web, or may be I am searching wrong keywords.

Anyone can please help  me ?

The lines in a list item, shows as moving. I am giving the screenshot of Flipkart App - My Orders Section

[image]

Comment: [Create your own progress bar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)

Answer (score 6):

The view effect in the screenshot is called **Shimmer Effect**.

There are a lot of good examples and open-source libraries available that provide a shimmer effect.

1. [Facebook Shimmer](http://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/) This library provided a skeleton layout that can be used with any layout.
2. [Shimmer RecyclerView](https://github.com/sharish/ShimmerRecyclerView) This library specifically provides shimmer effect in RecyclerView

You can also look at various tutorials available which can help you implement this behavior.

1. https://www.androidhive.info/2018/01/android-content-placeholder-animation-like-facebook-using-shimmer/
2. https://codinginfinite.com/facebook-shimmer-effect-android-example/

By following the first tutorial you will be able to achieve: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-TPBl39rDk&feature=emb_title)

[image: Tutorial Result]

Comment: thanks for telling this effect's name, Schimmer-effect.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use [Shimmer for Android library](https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android) and make a loading-layout like this

```
    <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/shimmer_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:tag="layout/component_loading_0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@drawable/divider_drawable"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="middle" android:tag="binding_1">

            <include layout="@layout/view_placeholder" />

            <include layout="@layout/view_placeholder" />

            <include layout="@layout/view_placeholder" />

            <include layout="@layout/view_placeholder" />

            <include layout="@layout/view_placeholder" />

            <include layout="@layout/view_placeholder" />

            <include layout="@layout/view_placeholder" />

            <include layout="@layout/view_placeholder" />

            <include layout="@layout/view_placeholder" />

            <include layout="@layout/view_placeholder" />

            <include layout="@layout/view_placeholder" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think waveLoad like animation may be useful for You.
So Design your own animation or use these libraries:

[WaveLoadingView1](https://github.com/tangqi92/WaveLoadingView)

[WaveLoadingView2](https://github.com/Neils320/WaveLoadingView-2)

Comment: These libraries mentioned will not solve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of views are called skeleton views.

You can create skeletons for your view and show that skeleton view with shimmer animation at the time of loading  instead of usual progress bar.

You can take a look at [this library](https://github.com/ethanhua/Skeleton)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is [Shimmer-android](http://facebook.github.io/shimmer-android/) animation that made by Facebook. 
This is a good [example](https://www.androidhive.info/2018/01/android-content-placeholder-animation-like-facebook-using-shimmer/) to implement it.